# Selection of feature class

Tags: arcgis-9.3

Currently, I would select a bunch of polylines in a fgdb, using Selection > Selection by Location. I will then be using a "AOI" (Area of Interest) polygon to help me select the polylines in a fgdb that are within AOI (usually, i will choose "are completely within" option), and these selected polylines will appear on one of my mxds.

I would like to have a script that can help me do this: running the selection of polylines using AOI polygon as a reference. So, whenever i open up that mxd, i will be able to see the updated polylines on it. [image]

FYI, the feature class in fgdb will be updated monthly (names of fgdb and its dataset remain unchanged), and there might be a increase or decrease in the number of polylines every month (there are to be captured as long as there are within the AOI.

Comment: All this you may do with Python and ArcPy, see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000? A lot of materials in this regard you'll find on this forum and ESRI website.

Comment: ArcPY is not available for ArcGIS 9.3.1.

Comment: Do you want to script this in Python?

Comment: @Chad, I do not mind python, if it works in 9.3.1 and you can show me a website on how to write a script for this. Ptython and GIS beginner here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a VBA script for ArcMap 9.3.1

Take a look at this post on esri forum as an example:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=146845

Comment: thanks, Alex. But i do not know much abt VBA. can you advise which lines are the input for AOI and the selection elements (polylines)? and what do they mean by saying "Did you try using ISpatialIndex.AllowIndexing = true, then calling ISpatialIndex.Invalidate on the geometry bag before putting it into the spatialfilter?"?